# javascript JSON parsing

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, recursion

I'm working against this JSON, trying to get all the keys and values. My issue is, in some cases there are inner objects with more keys and values in them,

Can this be done ONLY recursively in JavaScript? What am I missing?

```
{
  "@xmlns:v6": "urn://oracle.bi.webservices/v6",
  "v6:pageID": "?",
  "v6:reportID": "?",
  "v6:report": {
    "v6:reportPath": "?",
    "v6:reportXml": "?"
  },
  "v6:reportViewName": "?",
  "v6:reportParams": {
    "comment": [
      "Zero or more repetitions: ",
      "Zero or more repetitions: ",
      "Zero or more repetitions: ",
      "Zero or more repetitions: ",
      "Optional: "
    ],
    "v6:filterExpressions": "?",
    "v6:variables": {
      "v6:name": "?",
      "v6:value": "?"
    },
    "v6:nameValues": {
      "v6:name": "?",
      "v6:value": "?"
    },
    "v6:templateInfos": {
      "v6:templateForEach": "?",
      "v6:templateIterator": "?",
      "comment": "Zero or more repetitions: ",
      "v6:instance": {
        "v6:instanceName": "?",
        "comment": "Zero or more repetitions: ",
        "v6:nameValues": {
          "v6:name": "?",
          "v6:value": "?"
        }
      }
    },
    "v6:viewName": "?"
  },
  "v6:options": {
    "v6:enableDelayLoading": "?",
    "v6:linkMode": "?"
  },
  "v6:sessionID": "?"
}
```

Here's the code I'm trying to work with:

```
    function parse(data,child,parent){
    var nextRept = false;
        if(child){  
        for(var i = 0; i < tmp.parents.length ; i++){
            if(tmp.parents[i].name == parent){
                if(!tmp.parents[i].children)
                    tmp.parents[i].children = [];
                var keys = Object.keys(data);
                for (var k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
                var val = data[keys[k]];
                if(typeof val === 'object')
                {
                 tmp.parents.push({name: keys[k].replace("v6:","")} ); //adding the parent
                 parse(val,true,keys[k].replace("v6:","")); // adding children recursively 
                }
                if(val == '?')
                { // handle valid param
                    var attr = false;
                    if(keys[k].indexOf('@') == 0){
                        attr = true;
                        keys[k] = keys[k].replace("@","");
                    }
                    tmp.parents[i].children.push({name: keys[k].replace("v6:","") , value : val , isAttr : attr , isRepet : nextRept});
                    isRepet = false;
                }
                }
                return;
            }

        }
            return;
        }

        var keys = Object.keys(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            var val = data[keys[i]];
            if(typeof val === 'object')
                {
                 tmp.parents.push({name: keys[i].replace("v6:","")} ); //adding the parent
                 parse(val,true,keys[i].replace("v6:","")); // adding children recursively 
                }
                else{

                if(val.indexOf('Zero or more repetitions') != -1){
                    nextRept = true;
                    continue;
                }
                if(val == '?')
                { // handle valid param
                    var attr = false;
                    if(keys[i].indexOf('@') == 0){
                        attr = "true";
                        keys[i] = keys[i].replace("@","");
                    }
                    else{
                        attr = false;
                    }
                    tmp.parents.push({name: keys[i].replace("v6:","").replace("@","") , value : val , isAttr : attr , isRepet : nextRept});
                    isRepet = false;
                }


                }
            }

    };
```

Comment: You're missing... the code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Or rather than what have you tried, what is it that you are attempting to do? You haven't told us, so how can we tell you how to do it?

Comment: i've added a small code example (without recursion solution yet)

Comment: Are you working with some requirement that says you're not allowed to use recursion? Again, what is it that you are **trying** to do? Please describe it in words, and not just in code.

Comment: At least please show us what you want your final result to look like, based on that example input.

Comment: im trying to get all this json into array with the same hierarchy, which means , if it has children they will be in sub array, and so on..

Comment: i've also added the full parsing code im currently using , which works half way... if the level gets deep (object which contains array and such) the recursion wont work so good :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote this up pretty quickly but it should work for this situation. (Iteration through objects/arrays/strings) .

```javascript
var obj = {
    "item":     "value",
    "item2":    ["value1","value2","value3"],
    "item3":    {"item3-1": ["item3-1-1", "item3-1-2", "item3-1-3"], "item3-2": {"morestuff": ["morestuff1", "morestuff2","morestuff3"]}}
}

function parseObject(obj){
    for (var key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var item    = obj[key];
        if(typeof item == 'string'){
            console.log(key + ' -> ' + obj[key]);
        }else{
            console.log(key + ' -> ');
            parseObject(item);
        }
      }
    }
}

parseObject(obj);
```

Results in:

`item -> value
item2 ->
0 -> value1
1 -> value2
2 -> value3
item3 ->
item3-1 ->
0 -> item3-1-1
1 -> item3-1-2
2 -> item3-1-3
item3-2 ->
morestuff ->
0 -> morestuff1
1 -> morestuff2
2 -> morestuff3`

Comment: Thanks Shai! it gave me the right thinking direction!